# React Router Dom v6 useNavigate to Conditional Path Directory After Login

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

**Here I am passing navigate from login to useFirebase**

```
 let navigate = useNavigate();
const handleLoginSubmit = (e) => {
        loginUser(loginData.email, loginData.password, navigate);
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert('Login Successful');
    }
```

**This is loginUser control in useFirebase**

```
// user login
    const loginUser = (email, password, navigate) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                const destination = navigate?.state?.from || '/';
                navigate(destination);
                // navigate('/appointment');
                // Signed in 
                const user = userCredential.user;
                // ...
                setAuthError('');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                setAuthError(error.message);
            })
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }
```

**I am trying to add a condition rendering in navigate. When the user will log in it will redirect to which components, where he was trying to go before PrivateRoute, interfere to log in the user**

Comment: In fact, you want see that for the moment, this navigate?.state?.from is empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you are capturing the route the user was originally attempting to  access. If your code is *not* doing this then this is the gist for capturing a redirect "referrer" to use after authenticating.

Example:

```
const AuthWrapper = ({ authenticated }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return authenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
}
```

In the code passing the `navigate` function and handling the login submission, access the passed referrer route state here, and pass this along to the `loginUser` callback.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { state } = useLocation();
const from = state?.from || "/";

const handleLoginSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  loginUser(loginData.email, loginData.password, navigate, from);
};
```

Access the passed `from` referrer value in the `loginUser` callback.

```
const loginUser = (email, password, navigate, destination) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      navigate(destination);
      // Signed in 
      const user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
      setAuthError('');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      setAuthError(error.message);
    })
    .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
};
```

It may be a little more clean to instead pass an `onAuthSuccess` callback, but this is subjective.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { state } = useLocation();
const from = state?.from || "/";

const handleLoginSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  loginUser(loginData.email, loginData.password, () => navigate(from));
};
```

...

```
const loginUser = (email, password, onAuthSuccess) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      onAuthSuccess();
      // Signed in 
      const user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
      setAuthError('');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      setAuthError(error.message);
    })
    .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
};
```